# Проблема в проверке IndexError: List index out of range Python 3.x

Tags: python, python-3.x

Доброго времени суток. Имею  [задачу на Stepic.org](https://stepic.org/lesson/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%BC-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8-3369/step/10). Возникли с ней некоторые трудности. Если быть точнее, на этапе проверок от list index out of range на последнем вложенном массиве все кроме последнего элемента идут не в ту проверку, и в следствии чего выдаёт Error. Сам код (самый говнокодистый говнокод)

```
a = []
st = ''
while True:
    st = input()
    if st == 'end':
        break
    else:
        row = list(map(int, st.split()))
        a.append(row)

x = len(a[0])

b = [[0 for j in range(x)] for i in range(x)]

for i in range(x):  #тут начинаются тонны проверок для 'List index out of range' и параллельно проверкам заполнение нового массива
    for j in range(x):
        print(i,j) #вывод для понимания, все ли я делал правильно
        if i == 0:
            if j == 0:
                s = a[i + 1][j] + a[-1][j] + a[i][j + 1] + a[i][-1]
            if j == x - 1:
                s = a[i + 1][j] + a[-1][j] + a[i][0] + a[i][j - 1]
            else:
                s = a[i + 1][j] + a[-1][j] + a[i][j + 1] + a[i][j - 1]
            b[i][j] = s
        if i == x - 1:
            if j == 0:
                s = a[0][j] + a[i - 1][j] + a[i][j + 1] + a[i][-1]
            if j == x - 1:
                s = a[0][j] + a[i - 1][j] + a[i][0] + a[i][j - 1]
            else:
                s = a[0][j] + a[i - 1][j] + a[i][j + 1] + a[i][j - 1]
            b[i][j] = s
        if j == 0:
            if i == 0:
                s = a[i + 1][j] + a[-1][j] + a[i][j + 1] + a[i][-1]
            if i == x - 1:
                s = a[0][j] + a[i - 1][j] + a[i][j + 1] + a[i][-1]
            else:
                s = a[i + 1][j] + a[i - 1][j] + a[i][j + 1] + a[i][1]
            b[i][j] = s
        if j == x - 1:
            if i == 0:
                s = a[i + 1][j] + a[0][j] + a[i][0] + a[i][j - 1]
            if i == x - 1:
                s = a[0][j] + a[i - 1][j] + a[i][0] + a[i][j - 1]
            else:
                s = a[i + 1][j] + a[i - 1][j] + a[i][0] + a[i][j - 1]
            b[i][j] = s
        else:   #а эта ветка проверки, в которую уходит по ошибке последняя строка матрицы, кроме последнего, из за чего вылетает ошибка
            try:
                s = a[i + 1][j] + a[i - 1][j] + a[i][j + 1] + a[i][j - 1]
                b[i][j] = s
            except:
                b[i][j] = i, j
for i in b:
    for j in i:
        print(j,end='\t')
    print() #выводы для понимания, всё ли я делал правильно
print(b)
```

Если вы поможете понять, почему происходит переход в другую ветку проверки-буду очень благодарен.

P.S. Решения задачи не нужны. Интернет полон их

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По условиям задачи на вход подаётся прямоугольная матрица.

Тоесть реально матрица `а` имеет размерность m × n.

Но обход идёт по матрице n×n (x=n)

Если m < n, то будет выход за пределы массива (что и происходит в программе).

На квадратных матрицах программа не падает.
На матрицах в которых число строк больше числа столбцов тоже не падает, но выдаёт неверный ответ.

Обновление:

Управление переходит в блок к try из-за того что для ветвления вы используете не исключающие `if`, а не `elif`

Пусть 
Есть квадратная матрица (3x3) и i = 2 и j = 0.

Тогда:

```
 if i == 0: #  Не выполнится
 if i == x - 1: # выполнится
 if j == 0: # тоже будет проверятся т.к. это отдельный if (выполнится)
 if j == x - 1: # Не выполнится
 else: # т.к. этот else отностися к последнему if то он выполнится
 #т.к. i находится на последней строке
 # выражение `s = a[i + 1][j]...` приведет к выходу за пределы массива
```

Comment: проблема в том, что на квадратных матрицах программа падает. Она выдает результат по моему try: ... except: .... На счет ее прямоугольности решить будет куда проще. Для меня главное проблема с квадратной хотя бы

Comment: черт, проглядел это. сечас обновлю ответ.

Comment: Дополнил ответ.

Comment: я исправил все if на elif, и все заработало. Осталось поправить момент с прямоугольностью матрицы. Спасибо огромное. Не могу додуматься до этого несколько часов